# Run same operation on multiple columns with assign?

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for a short way to run the same operation on multiple columns - typically by running it through `.assign`.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[' abc ', 'efg', ' hij'], 'b': [' kkk ', 'eee', 'uuu ']})
```

In this example I have two columns with strings, some of which have leading and trailing spaces. If I want to remove them I would do something like this:

```
df.assign(a=lambda x: x["a"].str.strip(), b=lambda x: x["b"].str.strip())
```

basically repeating the same lambda expression for every column. Is there a more convenient way? I do not want to run a loop, because that cannot be method-chained.

My first idea was something like this, following the "don't repeat yourself" principle:

```
df.assign({col : lambda x: x[col].str.strip() for col in ['a', 'b']})
```

which of course does not work.

Any suggestions very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to [unpack the dictionary to parameters](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/dict_unpack.html) using `**`:

```
df.pipe(lambda d: d.assign(**{col : d[col].str.strip() for col in ['a', 'b']}))
```

output:

```
     a    b
0  abc  kkk
1  efg  eee
2  hij  uuu
```

ref: [PEP 448](https://peps.python.org/pep-0448/) for dictionary unpacking

Comment: Oh, I just realized something, this is unfortunately not working. You can see that the contents of both columns are the same, whereas they should not be! Column `a` should be `['abc', 'efg', 'hij']`. Something goes wrong, but I cannot yet say what.

Comment: @divingTobi you need to use `pipe` to have the lambda outside of the dictionary comprehension, check the update

Answer (score 0):

You can run a lambda on multiple columns by using a double bracket option

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[' abc ', 'efg', ' hij'], 'b': [' kkk ', 'eee', 'uuu ']})

df[['a', 'b']] = df[['a', 'b']].apply(lambda x : x.str.strip())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works, but I cannot use it for method chaining. Cheers!

Comment: No problem, if it doesn't work for this one I suppose you can just keep it for another situation it would work better on! Hope it helps in the future.